How to sign the configurations in FIT image using external tool
During the build process using the Buildroot the whole FIT image is generated. The configurations in FIT images should be signed and then verified using public keys in U-Boot during boot.
Signing the configurations using private key is pretty easy the signature node can be added in the ITS:
configurations {
  default = "kernel_dtb";

  kernel_dtb {
    description = "Linux kernel and FDT blob";
    kernel = "kernel";
    fdt = "base_fdt";
    signature {
      algo = "sha256,ecdsa256";
      key-name-hint = "sign-key";
      sign-images = "kernel", "fdt";
    };
  };
};

Then the signature is generated based on sign-key file.
But, the challenge is how to sign configuration section in case, when we don't have a private keys and we need to use external tool that provides signing functionality?
I mean - we can pass the binary and then receive signature for those data.
How to proceed?
I'm considering two approaches but I'm not sure if they are feasible:

Using the dumpimage it's possible to get the binary from the .itb image. Then we can generate signature for it.
Question: Is there any way to put this signature back into the .itb image?

During the build process before generating of the .itb it's possible to generate the signatures for each object that will go to FIT but:
Question: Is there any way to point the signature that should be attached to each configuration instead of generating it using the private keys?


General question: Or maybe this should be done totally different way? If so - how?
Thanks for all your help.
